# Bootstrap grid not displaying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a problem getting the bootstrap grid to display properly. My code is as follows

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

All I see is:
[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgToX.jpg)

Anyone know what's happening here? I have all the bootstrap.css, bootstrap-theme.css, and bootstrap.js properly included. Other things such as buttons are bring properly formatted by bootstrap.

Comment: That is correct structure, and your screenshot looks fine. This structure should split the line in two equal columns just like your screenshot suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see your 2 `div`'s are formatted as they should? (Using Boostraps md-6).

You don't need the `.col-md-6` value in your `div` though:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">Your text here</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Your text here</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

For more information check out the official Bootstrap Documentation page on [Grid Templates](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/examples/grid/)

For the grid view used in the documentation ([grid.css](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/examples/grid/grid.css)) add the following CSS:

```
h4 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row .row {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}

hr {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why the grid itself isn't actually displaying though. As per the link I posted, it's just text on a white background. No color, no grid.

Comment: The .col-md-6 value is just for testing

Comment: What is it you expect to happen? I think you've misunderstood the functionality of Bootstrap columns

Comment: I expect there to be a grid like the example in the Grid Templates online that you just linked to me

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding? Do I still need to create the CSS rule for the grid's background colors and what not.

Answer (score 2):

Modify as below

```
<div class="container show-grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

add the following css to your style sheet

```
.show-grid div{
  border:1px solid ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap makes an "invisible" grid if you want to see it that way, if you want to make the grid visible you can do it with css either adding a background color or border, my favorite is background color:

css:

```
.y0 { background-color: #CCC; }
.y1 { background-color: #9FF; }
.y2 { background-color: #F9F; }
.y3 { background-color: #F99; }
.y4 { background-color: #FF6; }
.y5 { background-color: #3C3; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 y0">Your text here</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 y1">Your text here</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```